# How to store user details after paypal payment approval?

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I'm building an online courses website, where students can buy a course via PayPal. The payment process is working successfully, But I'm confused on where or how to store course and user data after PayPal Payment Approval.

I have a users table, courses table and pivot table: course_students where I store the id of the course and the id of the student:

```
-------------
course_students
--------------
student_id    course_id
    1            2
----------
```

This is PayPalService Class:

```
class PayPalService
{
    use ConsumesExternalServices;

    protected $baseUri;

    protected $clientId;

    protected $clientSecret;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->baseUri = config('services.paypal.base_uri');
        $this->clientId = config('services.paypal.client_id');
        $this->clientSecret = config('services.paypal.client_secret');
    }

    public function resolveAuthorization(&$queryParams, &$formParams, &$headers)
    {
        $headers['Authorization'] = $this->resolveAccessToken();
    }

    public function decodeResponse($response)
    {
        return json_decode($response);
    }

    public function resolveAccessToken()
    {
        $credentials = base64_encode("{$this->clientId}:{$this->clientSecret}");

        return "Basic {$credentials}";
    }

    public function handlePayment(Request $request)
    {
        $order = $this->createOrder($request->value, $request->currency);

        $orderLinks = collect($order->links);

        $approve = $orderLinks->where('rel', 'approve')->first();

        session()->put('approvalId', $order->id);

        return redirect($approve->href);
    }

    public function handleApproval()
    {
        if (session()->has('approvalId')) {
            $approvalId = session()->get('approvalId');

            $payment = $this->capturePayment($approvalId);
            $name = $payment->payer->name->given_name;
            $payment = $payment->purchase_units[0]->payments->captures[0]->amount;
            $amount = $payment->value;
            $currency = $payment->currency_code;

            return redirect()
                ->route('success')
                ->with('payment', "Thanks, {$name}. We received your {$amount}{$currency} payment.");
        }

//        $errorMessage = 'We cannot capture the payment. Try again, please';
        return redirect()
            ->route('paymentform')
            ->with('error','We cannot capture the payment. Try again, please');
    }

    public function createOrder($value, $currency)
    {
        return $this->makeRequest(
            'POST',
            '/v2/checkout/orders',
            [],
            [
                'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
                'purchase_units' => [
                    0 => [
                        'amount' => [
                            'currency_code' =>strtoupper($currency),
                            'value' => round($value * $factor = $this->resolveFactor($currency)) / $factor,
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'application_context' => [
                    'brand_name' => config('app.name'),
                    'shipping_preference' => 'NO_SHIPPING',
                    'user_action' => 'PAY_NOW',
                    'return_url' => route('approval'),
                    'cancel_url' => route('cancelled'),
                ]
            ],
            [],
            $isJsonRequest = true,
        );
    }

    public function capturePayment($approvalId)
    {
        return $this->makeRequest(
            'POST',
            "/v2/checkout/orders/{$approvalId}/capture",
            [],
            [],
            [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
            ],
        );
    }

    public function resolveFactor($currency)
    {
        $zeroDecimalCurrencies = ['JPY'];

        if (in_array(strtoupper($currency), $zeroDecimalCurrencies)) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 100;
    }

}
```

PaymentController:

```
public function paymentForm($course_uuid)
    {
        $currencies = Currency::all();
        $platforms = PaymentPlatform::get();

        $course = Course::where('uuid', $course_uuid)->where('status',1)->where('availability',1)->first();

        return view('public.payment.paypalform', compact('currencies','platforms','course'));
    }

    /**
     * implment Payemnt process
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function pay(Request $request)
    {
//        dd($request->all());
        $rules = [
            'value' => ['required', 'numeric', 'min:5'],
            'currency' => ['required', 'exists:currencies,iso'],
            'payment_platform' => ['required', 'exists:payment_platforms,id'],
        ];

        $request->validate($rules);

        $paymentPlatform = $this->paymentPlatformResolver
            ->resolveService($request->payment_platform);

        session()->put('paymentPlatformId', $request->payment_platform);

        return $paymentPlatform->handlePayment($request);
    }

    protected function approval()
    {
        if (session()->has('paymentPlatformId')) {
            $paymentPlatform = $this->paymentPlatformResolver
                ->resolveService(session()->get('paymentPlatformId'));

            return $paymentPlatform->handleApproval();
        }else{
            return redirect()
                ->route('courses.levels')
                ->withErrors('We cannot retrieve your payment platform. Try again, please.');
        }

    }

    protected function canceled()
    {
        return redirect()
            ->route('courses.levels')
            ->withErrors('You cancelled the payment.');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  your payment controller you can save you the course information in session. After payment when user  will redirect, save the information  to your desired database table..

```
//save course info or other  info
session()->put('courseInfo', [your data]);
```

your controller function:

```
   /** 
     * implment Payemnt process
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function pay(Request $request)
    {
//        dd($request->all());
        $rules = [
            'value' => ['required', 'numeric', 'min:5'],
            'currency' => ['required', 'exists:currencies,iso'],
            'payment_platform' => ['required', 'exists:payment_platforms,id'],
        ];

        $request->validate($rules);

        $paymentPlatform = $this->paymentPlatformResolver
            ->resolveService($request->payment_platform);

        session()->put('paymentPlatformId', $request->payment_platform);

        //save course info or other  info
        session()->put('courseInfo', [your data]);


        return $paymentPlatform->handlePayment($request);
    }
```

you another function: `approval()` call another function `$paymentPlatform->handleApproval();` inside of it after payment done.

Go  to `handleApproval()` function and hopefully you will find there user account creation codes. Now get  the session value `session()->get('courseInfo')` and save in your desired table.